# SQL выборка из базы выдает ошибку

Tags: sql

пишу такой запрос:

```
SELECT * 
FROM file_multi 
WHERE post_id = '339424' 
ORDER BY index DESC
```

Но база возвращает мне почему-то ошибку:

> `#1064` - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near `'index LIMIT 0, 30'` at line 1

Запрос вроде бы корректный.

структура таблицы:

```
id  | filename | index | top | post_id | description 
543 | http...  |   4   |  0  | 339424  | skfkskfksmf 
544 | http...  |   1   |  0  | 339424  | skfkskfksmf 
545 | http...  |   2   |  0  | 339424  | skfkskfksmf 
546 | http...  |   3   |  0  | 339424  | skfkskfksmf
```

Comment: наверное, база данных вам таки сообщение подлиннее выдает. Приведите его целиком. И укажите СУБД, которую используете в тэгах вопроса с помощью [edit]

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: Вомзожно, `order by index` у вас не работает, ибо `index` весьма специфическое слово. В зависимости от диалекта, заключите его в скобки `[]` или кавычки `\`\``

Comment: у меня в бд таблица идет таким образом
id | filename | index | top | post_id | description
543 | http... | 4 | 0 | 339424 | skfkskfksmf
544 | http... | 1 | 0 | 339424 | skfkskfksmf
545 | http... | 2 | 0 | 339424 | skfkskfksmf
546 | http... | 3 | 0 | 339424 | skfkskfksmf

Comment: мне нужно сортировать все что в index и вывести

Comment: если mysql то напишите `order by \`index\` desc` - добавьте обратные кавычки.

Comment: ооо, заработало, большое спасибо тебе )

Comment: оформил ответом

Comment: @CyberX Настоятельная рекомендация - если не поздно, переименуйте это поле (и все остальные поля, совпадающие по написанию с зарезервированными словами). Это может сильно упростить жизнь в будущем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы используете ключевы слова (`index`) в качестве имен столбцов. Формально, конечно, это допустимо, но при этом при использовании имена столбцов надо соответствующим образом экранировать. В зависимости от диалекта СУБД это могут быть обратные кавычки `` `index` `` (mysql) либо квадратные скобки `[index]` (sql-server).
Для избежания таких ситуаций проще отказаться от использования такого именования столбцов, благо всегда можно придумать альтернативу: `idx, num, sort, ord` или для особых эстетов `poryadok` и т.д.

```
SELECT * 
FROM file_multi 
WHERE post_id = '339424' 
ORDER BY `index` DESC
```

*зы: одинарные кавычки вокруг `339424` тоже не нужны.*
*зы2: в зависимости от настроек, иногда имена полей и названия таблиц  обязательно требуется заключать в кавычки*